# dotnet get caller with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, stack-trace

in the load event of form1 there's this code, why the condition is always false even if the caller is form1?

how do i get the instance of the caller to read a property?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Utility.DoSomething();
}
//in a static class called utility
public static void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ManageException(ex);
    }
}

//in a static class called utility
public static void ManageException(Exception ex)
{
 StackTrace st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
  for (int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; i++)
    if (st.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().DeclaringType is System.Windows.Forms.Form)
     Console.Write("i need to get the form instance to access the name property");
}
```

Comment: What method declared by `Form` are you expecting to be in the stack trace? Have you looked at the stack trace to try to diagnose it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? getting the stack trace with the current method and class name? If so I have alternate code for that...

Comment: i want to test if the caller of the method that throw the exception is System.Windows.Forms.Form

Comment: i found the way to check if the current frame's type is System.Windows.Forms.Form , in the code above replace if (st.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().DeclaringType is System.Windows.Forms.Form) with if typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form).IsAssignableFrom(st.GetFrame(i).GetMethod().DeclaringType). Also i suppose to be impossible to get the instance of that form trough reflection